# Python Qt - Use button via function from outside a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I am quite new to python. For my problem I cannot seem to find an answer. And sadly I didn't find anything that could held me. I try to call a function from another file in the same folder but it won't work. If I call the same function from the same file, it works just fine. The same goes for external classes.
This code works:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from ui.mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.show()

        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(test_function)


def test_function(): 
    window.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(1)

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The following code won't work:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from ui.mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow
from other_file import test_function

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.show()

        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(test_function)



if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

> other_file.py

```
def test_function():
    window.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(1)
```

Error: cannot import name 'test_function'

Comment: The problem is simple: window is not defined in the other file so it should not work, your example has a problem in the background, the problem is your bad design, so the solution is to change your design, why do you want to use others? files that use a resource created in the main file?

Comment: I already tried to import window in the other file. Still did not work. This is not the usual design I use. But I wanted to try something and came upt to this problem. Now I want to know why this occurs.

Comment: You can not and must not import window in other_file.py because you would be creating an infinite loop of import. The problem is your bad design.

Comment: Ah now I get it :) thanks